# Crash of matplotlib window with anaconda

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, conda, miniconda

I'm currently trying to run this python script in VSCODE with a miniconda kernel:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(100)
Y = np.random.rand(100)

plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the matplotlib window opens and crahes directly. If I paste the code on a notebook it works perfectly and print the figure but from a .py file it keeps crashing. I recently moved to conda and I hadn't had this problem on a classic python version.

I tried to install matplotlib through conda or pip but the result is the same. I also tried to downgrade freetype but it didn't work. I also updated conda and every packages to their latest version.
If anyone has an idea on how to solve this, please let me know.

Comment: Does saving the image works? eg `plt.savefig('test.png', dpi = 600)` before `plt.show()`